# Get multiple params with one get request

Tags: python, json, api, python-requests

i want to request data from an API but I'm struggling to get multiple `params` within one request.

I have the following line of code:

```
r = requests.get('https://api.delta.exchange/v2/tickers?contract_types= call_options, put_options')
```

According to the API documentation the `params` for each contract_type can be called by separating with a comma. While using the line above it will only return the first called `param` in that case `call_options`. I tried separating with an `&` with the same effect. For some reason using `request.get(url, params={call_options,put_options})` results in the error that `call_options` is not defined.

Probably a very trivial problem but I'm thankful for any help or suggestion.

[image]

Comment: The *variables* `call_options` and `put_options` are not defined; you want to pass a set of *strings*: `requests.get(url, params={'call_options', 'put_options'})`.

Comment: That would still be wrong, though: `requests.get(url, params={'contract_types': 'call_options,put_options'})` should work.

Answer (score 1):

The correct argument for the `params` parameter would be a `dict` whose key is the parameter name and the value would be the comma-separated string.

```
r = requests.get('https://api.delta.exchange/v2/tickers',
                 param={'contract_types': 'call_options,put_options'})
```

Answer (score 1):

I cannot reproduce why your line of code should only give you "call options".

The following example and the according output shows that the API is returning the expected types.

```
urls = ['https://api.delta.exchange/v2/tickers?contract_types=call_options', 
'https://api.delta.exchange/v2/tickers?contract_types=put_options',
'https://api.delta.exchange/v2/tickers?contract_types=call_options,put_options']

for url in urls:
    r = requests.get(url)
    print(f"URL: {url}")
    print(f"Occurences of call_options: {r.text.count('call_option')}")
    print(f"Occurences of put_options: {r.text.count('put_options')}")
    print("")
```

Output:

```
URL: https://api.delta.exchange/v2/tickers?contract_types=call_options
Occurences of call_options: 366
Occurences of put_options: 0

URL: https://api.delta.exchange/v2/tickers?contract_types=put_options
Occurences of call_options: 0
Occurences of put_options: 372

URL: https://api.delta.exchange/v2/tickers?contract_types=call_options,put_options
Occurences of call_options: 366
Occurences of put_options: 372
```

In general, you should avoid using spaces in URLs.